# What is wrong with my Quaternion rotation in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, rotation, quaternions

Going off notes on the internet helps construct quaternion classes properly. My problem is putting them to practical use and using them for rotations in raw OpenGL.

In my input events I have the following:

```
Quaternion<float> qPrev = qRot;
qRot = qRot.UnitQuaternion(); // #1.
Quaternion<float> axis(5., 0., 1., 0.);
qRot = qPrev*axis;
qRot *= qPrev.conjugate();
//#2. qRot = qRot.UnitQuaternion();
```

If I use #1 make the rotation result unit it rotates fine for a few seconds, speeds up and then vanishes completely .

If I use #2 for a unit result the box "wobbles" and never rotates.

Alternatively, I've used this based off other implementations:

```
Quaternion<float> qPrev = qRot;
Quaternion<float> axis(-5./100, 0., 1., 0.); // #3.
axis = axis.UnitQuaternion();
qRot = qPrev*axis;
// #4. qRot *= qPrev.conjugate();
```

Where #3. makes the most sense, taking the unit of a non-unit quat and multiplying it initially with the identity quat; keeping everything in unit-quats.

Where #4. tried multiplying the conjugate based off my understanding of the equation's rotation definition.

All of these produce a small wobble and #1 is the closest I got; the box rotates, then quickly, then vanishes.

---

My understanding is that I have an axis I which to rotate around where w = how much (angle in radians). I simply multiply by the orientation and multiply that result by the negative of the orientation; e.g. the conjugate.

---

Rendering code (this could be the culprit):

```
// Apply some transformations
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -100.f);
glRotatef(qRot.x, 1., 0, 0);
glRotatef(qRot.y, 0, 1., 0);
glRotatef(qRot.z, 0, 0, 1.);

// Draw the cube
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

// Draw some text on top of our OpenGL object
window.pushGLStates();
```

---

I appreciate the help

---

**Edit: Many thanks to @ybungalobill for helping out**.

What I wanted from my quaternion is a very specific application in terms of quaternion math. I wanted an axis of rotation while in my example I'm creating a quaternion with the direct values. This is not how the rotation matrix is derived. I needed more steps:

```
void FromAxisAngle(_Tp theta, _Tp x, _Tp y, _Tp z)
{
    //Angle should be in radians
    this->w = cos(theta/2);

    //Axes
    this->x = x * sin(theta/2);
    this->y = y * sin(theta/2);
    this->z = z * sin(theta/2);
    //Normalize
    *this = this->UnitQuaternion();
}
```

Again, getting the rotation matrix is a very specific application with very specific steps. Quaternions don't do this 'out of the box'.

Some minor changes to the rotation logic as well:

```
   Quaternion<float> qPrev = qRot;
   Quaternion<float> axis;
   axis.FromAxisAngle(-5./100, 1., 0., 0.);
   qRot = qPrev*axis;
```

So now I've created a mathematically correct quaternion FROM my rotation axis. Then multiply.

Finally, the last thing I had to do was create a matrix from my quaternion that OpenGL could use. So we have more math to do in order to get it in a notation that rotates things:

```
void GetMatrix(_Tp matrix[16])
{
   Quaternion<_Tp> temp(this->UnitQuaternion());
  _Tp qw = temp.w;
  _Tp qx = temp.x;
  _Tp qy = temp.y;
  _Tp qz = temp.z;

  matrix[0] = 1.0f - 2.0f*qy*qy - 2.0f*qz*qz;
  matrix[1] = 2.0f*qx*qy - 2.0f*qz*qw;
  matrix[2] = 2.0f*qx*qz + 2.0f*qy*qw;
  matrix[3] = 0;

  matrix[4] = 2.0f*qx*qy + 2.0f*qz*qw;
  matrix[5] = 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qz*qz;
  matrix[6] = 2.0f*qy*qz - 2.0f*qx*qw;
  matrix[7] = 0;

  matrix[8] = 2.0f*qx*qz - 2.0f*qy*qw;
  matrix[9] = 2.0f*qy*qz + 2.0f*qx*qw;
  matrix[10] = 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qy*qy;
  matrix[11] = 0;

  matrix[12] = 0;
  matrix[13] = 0;
  matrix[14] = 0;
  matrix[15] = 1;
}
```

Using `glMultMatrix` the cube rotates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> glRotatef(qRot.x, 1., 0, 0);
> glRotatef(qRot.y, 0, 1., 0);
> glRotatef(qRot.z, 0, 0, 1.);
> ```

That's not how you apply a quaternion rotation to the GL state. You have to convert it to a matrix following the formula from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix) and then call `glMultMatrix` or `glMultTransposeMatrix`. After that approach number #3 will work as expected.

---

Code that converts any non-zero quaternion to a matrix, from Stannum libs:

```
template<class T>
mat<T,3,3> mat_rotation(const quat<T> &x)
{
    T s = 2/norm2(x); // cheap renormalization even of non-unit quaternions
    T wx = x.w*x.x, wy = x.w*x.y, wz = x.w*x.z;
    T xx = x.x*x.x, xy = x.x*x.y, xz = x.x*x.z;
    T yy = x.y*x.y, yz = x.y*x.z;
    T zz = x.z*x.z;

    return mat<T,3,3>(
        1 - s*(yy+zz),  s*(xy-wz),  s*(xz+wy),
        s*(xy+wz),  1 - s*(xx+zz),  s*(yz-wx),
        s*(xz-wy),  s*(yz+wx),  1 - s*(xx+yy)
    );
}
```

Comment: I've seen code that applies the matrix like you've stated but how can I *avoid* use the resulting matrix and use glRotatef instead?

Comment: @Maverick: you can't *avoid* the matrix, because eventually the legacy OpenGL transformations *work* with a *matrix* stack. You can recover the axis of rotation by `normalize(x,y,z)` and the angle by `2*atan2(length(x,y,z), w)` and then call `glRotate` on that *once*. But the next thing `glRotate` will do is calculate sine and cosine of that angle and calculate the said matrix... The question is *why* don't you want to do it the straightforward way?

Comment: Ok.I'm confused with this bit of code then:

https://pastebin.com/YSM6XSAc

If this rotates a point and returns an axis, why doesn't this work with glRotatef?

Comment: @Maverick: you don't need that (unless you do the transformation in a vertex shader that gets quaternions directly -- which you don't). That code applies a quaternion to *one* vector. What you need instead, is to express that transformation by matrix multiplication. If you do the algebra of that `q.QuatRotation(v)` you'll see that it equals exactly to `mat_rotation(q)*v`.

Comment: Ok so the issue is that I would want to be doing transformation of all 3 vectors representing the orientation of my object: x axis vector, y axis vector, z axis vector. So doing matrix multiplication treats the orientation as a system and computes it all in one go. The result, then is a matrix, that represents the steps the graphics device would need to take to rotate the object correctly. But since the device already uses matrices, we again apply this to the stack using glMultMatrix and it applies the proper rotations in one go as well. Is that about right?

Comment: @Maverick: Yes. That's right. Put it other way: legacy OpenGL works by applying its internal `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix `M` to each vertex `v` by `M*v`. Because OpenGL doesn't understand quaternions, you need to express `q.QuatRotation(v)` in a matrix-vector multiplication form, which `mat_rotation(q)*v` does. You store `M = mat_rotation(q)` in OpenGL's state, and then it substitutes different vertices `v` as necessary.